# facebook showing wrong description when share

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Live page- http://www.collectorsunleashed.com/spot-prices/

Facebook showing wrong description when i share that page. Any idea what is the problem & how can i fix that issue.

Code-

```
<title>Precious Metal Spot Prices | Gold, Silver, Platinum, Palladium</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="numismatics,vintage,antiques,collectibles,collecting,coins" />
<meta name="description" content="Up to the minute spot prices for gold, silver, platinum, and palladium. Each precious metal is also broken down into various world currencies including US Dollars, Canadian Dollars, Australian Dollars, Euros, Pounds Sterling, Swiss Francs, Yen, and Rand." />

<!-- for Facebook -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Precious Metal Spot Prices | Gold, Silver, Platinum, Palladium" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Up to the minute spot prices for gold, silver, platinum, and palladium. Each precious metal is also broken down into various world currencies including US Dollars, Canadian Dollars, Australian Dollars, Euros, Pounds Sterling, Swiss Francs, Yen, and Rand." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.collectorsunleashed.com/images/logo/whc53d45d2422ffb.png" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this built-in Facebook tool:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

That will give you a preview of what your share will look like, and it will also tell you exactly what it sees, and if/why certain things fail.

In either case, Facebook caches the first call made to the URL.  So sometimes, it appears to be showing an old version, even though you've made an update.  This gives you the chance to force that cache cleared.